# What episode in Naruto Shippuuden did they start the mission to seal the nibi?

Tags: naruto

I've stopped watching Naruto Shippuuden in the episodes where they were sealing Matatabi, the nibi (two-tailed beast). I want to continue watching but I'm not sure what episode to watch. So, what is the episode where the main topic is about the nibi and they are starting the mission to seal it?

Comment: The "bijuu" are the tailed beasts. Bijuu doesn't refer to one in particular, and they started looking for them in Naruto (pre-Shippuden). So I'm not really sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I mean the two-tailed beast, nibi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nibi was sealed in episode 81 of Naruto Shippuuden, *Sad News*. The whole mission starts in episode 71, *My Friend*, when Akatsuki starts chasing the nibi.